# How to execute a team scoreboard?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What I want to do is execute a particle command to that team and only that team from where ever they go. This was the original command:

Command block type = Repeat, unconditional, always active:

```
/execute @p[x=1903,y=5,z=2085,r=69,c=4] ~ ~ ~ /particle flame ~ ~1 ~ 0 0 0 0 10 100
```

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 1):

The `team` selector parameter allows you to target only those in a specific team. For example, the following only causes players in team "blue" to run `/particle`:

```
/execute @p[x=1903,y=5,z=2085,r=69,c=4,team=blue] ~ ~ ~ /particle flame ~ ~1 ~ 0 0 0 0 10 100
```

Comment: When you mean by team blue, do you mean make a scoreboard or something? @Skylinerw